# Math behind Conv2D function in Keras

Tags: math, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, convolution

I am using `Conv2D` model of `Keras 2.0`. However, I cannot fully understand what the function is doing mathematically. I try to understand the math using randomly generated data and a very simple network:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K

# create the model
inputs = Input(shape=(10,10,1)) # 1 channel, 10x10 image
outputs = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', name='block1_conv1')(inputs)
model = Model(outputs=outputs, inputs=inputs)

# input
x = np.random.random(100).reshape((10,10))

# predicted output for x
y_pred = model.predict(x.reshape((1,10,10,1))) # y_pred.shape = (1,8,8,32)
```

I tried to calculate, for example, the value of the first row, the first column in the first feature map, following the demo in [here](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#conv).

```
w = model.layers[1].get_weights()[0] # w.shape = (3,3,1,32)
w0 = w[:,:,0,0]
b = model.layers[1].get_weights()[1] # b.shape = (32,)
b0 = b[0] # b0 = 0

y_pred_000 = np.sum(x[0:3,0:3] * w0) + b0
```

But `relu(y_pred_000)` is not equal to `y_pred[0][0][0][0]`.

Could anyone point out what's wrong with my understanding? Thank you.

Comment: What are the results you get? When I ran your code I get `y_pred_000 = 0.14973172296210166` and `y_pred[0][0][0][0] = 0.14973173` which seems close enough.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The results I got (on Windows 10, python 2.7, K.backend() == theano) was `y_pred_000 = 0.091446961680955799` and `y_pred[0][0][0][0] = 0.033766586`. But after changing the back end to tensorflow (python 3.5, K.backend() == tensorflow), the two results were same! (`y_pred_000 = 0.025001197995700348` and `y_pred[0][0][0][0] = 0.025001198`) I suppose this is a theano or python2-specific problem.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy and it comes from `Theano` dim ordering. The result of applying filter in stored in a so called `channel` dimension. In case of `TensorFlow` this is the last dimension and that's why results are good. In case of `Theano` it's second dimension (convolution result has shape `(cases, channels, width, height)` so in order to solve your problem you need to change prediction line to:

```
y_pred = model.predict(x.reshape((1,1,10,10)))
```

Also you need to change the way you get the weights as weights in `Theano` has shape `(output_channels, input_channels, width, height)` you need to change the weight getter to:

```
w = model.layers[1].get_weights()[0] # w.shape = (32,1,3,3)
w0 = w[0,0,:,:]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I modified the code as you told, but I got the error: `ValueError: Error when checking : expected input_8 to have shape (None, 10, 10, 1) but got array with shape (1L, 1L, 10L, 10L)` I guess the `shape` of the `Input` does not match the shape of the reshaped input. How should I modify the code? (In my .keras.keras.json, `"image_data_format": "channels_last"`)

Comment: Ok - so leave the prediction line as it was and try only second change. How it works then?

Comment: Again I got the error: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,3) (1,32)`. The shape of `w[0,0,:,:]` is `(1,32)`, so it's not a kernel.

Comment: What are `y_pred` and `y_pred0000` shapes?

Comment: `y_pred`: `(1,8,8,32)`, `y_pred_000`: scalar